# Declaring more than one delegate in a given class

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols

I've declared two protocols

```
@protocol DeletedDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) deletedObj: (id) p_objDeleted;

@end

@protocol BrowseDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) nextObj: (id) p_currentObj;
- (void) previousObj: (id) p_currentObj;

@end
```

In my viewController.h file i've declared the delegates as follow:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<DeletedDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<BrowseDelegate> browseDelegate;
```

In viewController.m I have two actions that have the basically the same code

```
- (IBAction) previous_Clicked: (id) sender
{
    //If anyone is listening
    if ([self.browseDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(previousObj:)]==YES)
    {
        //send them the new status
        [self.browseDelegate previousObj:(self.currentObj)];
    }
}

- (IBAction) trashBin_Clicked: (id) sender
{

    //If anyone is listening
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(deletedObj:)]==YES)
    {
        //send them the new status
        [self.delegate deleteObj:(self.currentObj)];
    }
}
```

and in the UITableViewController next to the interface I have declared the two protocols `<DeletedDelegate, BrowseDelegate>` as well as implemented the functionality of `deleteObj` and `previousObj`

**Here is my problem**: in `previous_Clicked` this `[self.browseDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(previousObj:)]` will always return NO.

Now if I comment the delete delegate code and change the name of browseDelegate to delegate, it will work just fine.

How can I define multiply delegates/properties of protocols in a single class?

Comment: This code looks OK. Are you sure `browseDelegate` is not `nil`? Did you set it to an object? If it is an object, does that object have a `-previousObj:` method?

Comment: browseDelegate is NOT nil, i did set the object. as i wrote above if i only change it's name from browseDelegate to delegate, and comment the other delegate all works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it although I'm not sure why the above doesn't work but by posting the answer I hope it will contribute others

I changed viewController.h as follow:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<DeletedDelegate,BrowseDelegate> delegate;
```

and in my viewController.m

```
- (IBAction) previous_Clicked: (id) sender
{
    //If anyone is listening
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(previousObj:)]==YES)
    {
        //send them the new status
        [self.delegate previousObj:(self.currentObj)];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `delegate` is not a keyword and has no special meaning. Your problem is something else.